# Do we need a seperate load balancer for mobile application that using firebase as backend?

Tags: firebase, flutter, performance, mobile, load

Do we need a seperate load balancer for mobile application that using firebase as backend ? Is it able to handle if more users came ?

Comment: Not at all. Firebase handles autoscaling for you as traffic fluctuates since it replicates its data across multiple regions; your backend will work both for 10 users or 10M users, and with its multi-regional support, you'll be able to serve your users globally. That's the beauty of Firebase - it is part of Google Cloud's serverless offering, in which you don't have to manage any servers at all, it's all managed for you. You can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore)

Comment: Note though that Firebase is 18 or so products, so it's best to say exactly what Firebase products you use and how you use them. More details => better answers.